# Error creating Erlang project on eclipse through Erlide plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, erlang, eclipse-indigo, erlide

I ran into trouble when trying to install the Erlide plugin in eclipse for Erlang using the guide below:
"myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/erlang-getting-started-and-using-eclipse/"

and I have successfully installed Erlang on my PC and was able to link the binary files to the system "PATH".

However, when it came to installing the plugin on my eclipse Indigo, it first I could not find the repository: "http://erlide.sourceforge.net/update". But that easily fixed by changing the repo to "http://erlide.org/update" which give a list of tools to download, which happened seamlessly.

And this is when I started to wonder: "Could it really be that easy ?".

My doubts were soon confirmed when I went on to create a new project (File > New > Project... > Erlang > Erlang Project), which immediately gave me an error box of
"Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.erlide.ui (317)."

I've been googling this issue for a while now (~3 hours) with not even a hint to this issue. Is there anyone who has encountered this issue before ?

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is the error generated from it I hope it helps:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Sun Feb 09 16:46:35 EET 2014
Plug-in org.erlide.ui was unable to load class org.erlide.ui.views.ErlPatternMatchListenerDelegate.

org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.erlide.ui (469).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition$1.run(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.internalGetDecorator(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.erlide.ui.internal.ErlideUIPlugin for bundle org.erlide.ui is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/erlide/backend/api/IBackendListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.erlide.backend (453).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.erlide.backend.internal.BackendPlugin.start() of bundle org.erlide.backend.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "03-1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeVersion.<init>(RuntimeVersion.java:81)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeVersion.getVersion(RuntimeVersion.java:254)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeInfo.getVersion(RuntimeInfo.java:181)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeInfoCatalog.addRuntime(RuntimeInfoCatalog.java:64)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeInfoCatalog.initializeRuntimesList(RuntimeInfoCatalog.java:190)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeInfoCatalog.setRuntimes(RuntimeInfoCatalog.java:47)
    at org.erlide.runtime.api.RuntimeCore.getRuntimeInfoCatalog(RuntimeCore.java:20)
    at org.erlide.backend.BackendCore.getRuntimeInfoCatalog(BackendCore.java:28)
    at org.erlide.backend.internal.BackendPlugin.start(BackendPlugin.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 57 more
```

Thanks guys !

Regards.

Comment: if you really need an IDE I would recommend IntelliJ + http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7083?pr=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are using R16B03-1 and in that case you should use the latest beta (0.25.0) from http://download.erlide.org/update/beta. Please let me know if there are other problems.

regards,
Vlad